# Ввод в текстбокс только цифр

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Есть такой пример кода.
Я почитал MSDN про все методы, свойства.
Понял, что если пользователь вводит цифру или BACKSPACE, то в оператор не заходит,
а если вводит что-то другое, например букву, то срабатывает `e.Handled = true;` и в текстбокс ничего не запишется.

Объясните эту строчку `e.Handled = true;`
Я читал про этот параметр у `KeyPressEventArgs`, но не понял почему `true`, а не `false` тогда.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
        (e.KeyChar != '.'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если задать для параметра Handled элемента управления TextBox значение true, этот элемент управления не будет передавать события events о нажатии клавиши базовому элементу управления текстового поля Win32, однако он будет отображать символы, введенные пользователем.
Проверяется была ли нажата клавиша, не представляющая цифру. Если такая клавиша была нажата, событие KeyPress отменяется с помощью свойства Handled.

> Значение true для обхода обработки элемента управления по умолчанию; значение false для передачи события обработчику элементов управления по умолчанию.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Если представить, что `Handled` есть свойство  c именем `Блокировать`, то  
`e.Handled = true` можно представить в виде `Блокировать = истина`;